# How to print PHP dropdown in a loop using JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to print the text-box and the drop-down from a database. I am printing the text-box and drop-down based on the input given.

For example: say I am giving the input as 4. For that, it will create four text-boxes and drop-downs.

But I have the dropdown code in [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), so now I want to print the PHP dropdown in a loop using JavaScript. How can I do this?

JavaScript code:

```
function create(param) {
    'use strict';

    var i, target = document.getElementById('screens');
    target.innerHTML = '';

    for(i = 0; i < param; i += 1) {
       target.innerHTML +='</br>';
       target.innerHTML +='New Movie '+i+'  ';
       target.innerHTML += '<input type="text" name="Fname">';
       target.innerHTML +='  '+'Language '+'  ';
       target.innerHTML += '<input type="text" name="timings">';
       target.innerHTML +='</br>';
       target.innerHTML +='</br>';
    }
}
```

PHP dropdown:

```
<?php
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=theaterdb;host=localhost','tiger','tiger');
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $sql = "SELECT language FROM languages;";

    $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute();

    echo "<select name='language' id='course'>";
    echo "<option>----Select Language----</option>";
    while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['language'] ."'>" . $row['language']. "</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
?>
```

In place of

```
   target.innerHTML += '<input type="text" name="timings">';
```

I should get a PHP dropdown instead of a textbox.

Comment: Instead of printing html from the serverside, I would recommend sending it as a json string -> parse it on the client side -> create the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way, since you have both codes....

```
function create(param) {
    'use strict';

    var i, target = document.getElementById('screens');
    target.innerHTML = '';
<?php 
        try {
            $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=theaterdb;host=localhost','tiger','tiger');
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }

        $sql = 'SELECT language FROM languages;';

        $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute();
        $combo = "<select name='language' id='course'>";
        $combo .= "<option>----Select Language----</option>"; 
        while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $combo .= "<option value='" . $row['language'] ."'>" . $row['language']. "</option>";
        }
        $combo .= "</select>";
?>
    for(i = 0; i < param; i += 1) {
       target.innerHTML +='</br>';
       target.innerHTML +='New Movie '+i+'  ';
       target.innerHTML += '<input type="text" name="Fname">';
       target.innerHTML +='  '+'Language '+'  ';
       target.innerHTML += "<?php echo $combo; ?>";
       target.innerHTML +='</br>';
       target.innerHTML +='</br>';
    }
}
```